# In java, how to write an object to a file and later on read it from the file and convert it back to the original object in the HDFS?

Tags: java, hdfs

I am trying to write a double[] into a file in HDFS, and later on, I will need to read it back from the file and convert it back to the double[]. Does anyone here know how to do it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[ObjectOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html)**

> An ObjectOutputStream writes primitive data types and graphs of Java
>   objects to an OutputStream. The objects can be read (reconstituted)
>   using an ObjectInputStream. Persistent storage of objects can be
>   accomplished by using a file for the stream. If the stream is a
>   network socket stream, the objects can be reconstituted on another
>   host or in another process.
>
> Only objects that support the java.io.Serializable interface can be
>   written to streams. The class of each serializable object is encoded
>   including the class name and signature of the class, the values of the
>   object's fields and arrays, and the closure of any other objects
>   referenced from the initial objects.
>
> The method writeObject is used to write an object to the stream. Any
>   object, including Strings and arrays, is written with writeObject.
>   Multiple objects or primitives can be written to the stream. The
>   objects must be read back from the corresponding ObjectInputstream
>   with the same types and in the same order as they were written.
>
> Primitive data types can also be written to the stream using the
>   appropriate methods from DataOutput. Strings can also be written using
>   the writeUTF method.

**[ObjectInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html)**

> An ObjectInputStream deserializes primitive data and objects
>   previously written using an ObjectOutputStream.
>
> ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream can provide an application
>   with persistent storage for graphs of objects when used with a
>   FileOutputStream and FileInputStream respectively. ObjectInputStream
>   is used to recover those objects previously serialized. Other uses
>   include passing objects between hosts using a socket stream or for
>   marshaling and unmarshaling arguments and parameters in a remote
>   communication system.
>
> ObjectInputStream ensures that the types of all objects in the graph
>   created from the stream match the classes present in the Java Virtual
>   Machine. Classes are loaded as required using the standard mechanisms.

**For example,** I can save a key generator for encrypting data in this manner:

```
public static void saveKeyToFile(SecretKey key)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
            "/path/to/mysavedobject"));
    oos.writeObject(key);
    oos.close();
}

public static SecretKey getKeyFromFile(String dir) throws IOException,
        ClassNotFoundException {
    if (dir == null) { 
        dir = "/path/to/mysavedobject";
    }
    SecretKey key = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(
            dir));
    key = (SecretKey) ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
    return key;
}
```